# Is there a word that means "not yet open"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that means "not yet open". For example:

> Registration Status: (Open|Closed|XXX)

"Closed", while technically correct, can lead to confusion as it implies (in this case) that registration was open at one point in time. Also, due to length constraints, "Not yet open" cannot be used (8 characters or less is preferred).

Comment: "RSN" and "TBD" both are popular indicators that something will happen, respectively  meaning "real soon now" and "to be determined".

Comment: I think we need a tag that is "single-word-requests unrelated to programming."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The most direct choice that comes to my mind is [**unopened**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unopened):

> *Adj.* **1.** *unopened* - not yet opened or unsealed

…which also has the advantage of being 8 characters long.

Other terms that might work include **inactive**, **in wait**, and **idle**.

Comment: Or possibly **new**, but I don't know if that actually applies (i.e. how long is a registration in this not-yet-open state?).

Comment: @Marthaª, it can be in the "not-yet-open" stage for a one to two months. Cameron, great suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

How about *[pending](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pending?show=1&t=1341953929)* or *[imminent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imminent)*?

Comment: I was actually going to add a sentence about "pending" in the question. Regrettably, it won't work in this situation as it's going to be used internally, referring to the event status, which is *pending* as far as we're concerned, since we're waiting for it to close, before we can do anything. "Imminent" *may* work though, but I'm hoping for something a bit more clear in meaning [to us]. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @bfrohs I will keep my gears turning on this one.

Comment: @bfrohs: what about *waiting* then?

Comment: If _pending_ doesn't work, what about _impending_?  Just a thought...

Comment: I like pending the best of all answers. I offer also, Future, Forthcoming, Scheduled

Comment: @nico, "waiting" would also be confused with "open" in this case, as that is the stage *we* wait in. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @Tolerance72, I love "scheduled", but regrettably it's too long (at least for the question's requirements, but I may end up using it in my project anyway). I also glanced through synonyms, but couldn't find anything to my liking.

Comment: @bfrohs: *sched.* would be easily understood though

Comment: Another thought. If the dates of the registration are set, it is possible you could fit them in 8 characters. For example "8/1-9/15"

Answer (score 6):

*Upcoming*? (Plus some filler for the 30-character limit).

Answer (score 2):

How about "opening"? "The act or process of opening; a beginning; commencement; first appearance." (Wordnik.)
It seems that "opening" and "not yet open" are similar in meaning, and, at same time, that word is different both from "open" and from "closed" in the sense you explained.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, this doesn't feel appropriate in this case as "the act of opening" only takes a split second--I'm looking more for a word that describes the status prior to "opening".

Answer (score 1):

**Unreleased** gives the implication of not (yet) being available, although it is slightly longer than 8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the word *lock* can be used. That has only 4 letters.

Comment: *Locked* is better because that is a state, whereas *lock* is either an artefact or an action.